# PDI's "Replace in String" step with regex doing replace twice

Tags: regex, string, pentaho, pdi

What I'm trying to do is just concatenate arguments to my existing string "./executable.sh", so that output row set would look like that

```
./executable.sh argument1
./executable.sh argument3
./executable.sh argument2
  ...
  ...
```

Below is the "Replacement in string" step.
Search is set to (.*) . Replacement field is set to ./executable.sh $1

[image: Replace in string step]

Results that I'm getting are:

```
./executable.sh argument1./executable.sh 
./executable.sh argument2./executable.sh 
./executable.sh argument3./executable.sh
```

How come I'm getting the initial string added to the end of the replacement ?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I guess you just need to use `(.+)` or `^(.*)$`.

Comment: you're right. if you want to answer the question, im happy to accept. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your regex can match a null/empty string that is matched after the string (i.e. the engine behind the scenes splits the string into two parts: all the characters and the terminating null string, and thus you get two matches that are replaced).

To avoid that, you need to use either

```
(.+)
```

or

```
^(.*)$
```

The `(.+)` pattern matches 1 or more characters other than a newline, and `^(.*)$` matches 0 or more characters other than a newline from the start of the string (`^`) to the end of it (`$`). Explicit anchors in the second pattern help get rid of matching the null string at the end of the input.